# Do I have to wire up my WS2812 LED strip in "series", if I want to address each LED individually?

Tags: led, led-strip, ws2812

Let's assume I want to make an asterisk (`*`) out of LED strips. I want to control each leg individually, while still being connected to only one GPIO pin. The layout I had in mind, looks like this:

[image]

Since it's an LED strip with individually addressable LEDs, I can't just supply 5V, GND, and DATA to the middle and expect it to work (I highly assume).

If I want to do this, I assume I need to keep running them in "series", basically meaning I hook up one of the strips to the Arduino, then at the end of the strip I run a long wire to the start of one of the others and then repeat. Something like this:

[image]

but only for the data wire, as I can simply power all of them in the middle. If not, how can I do this? What happens if I hook up 5 strips' DATA to a single GPIO pin on the Arduino? Are all 5 strips shared then, so each strip's first LED is also the first I would turn on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LEDs are "addressed" in series; if you address the first LED then you address *all* connected first LEDs. So yes, you must connect the Data Out of the previous LED/strip to the Data In of the next in order to address all of them individually.

Comment: Right, so the second image I put in is basically what I have to do?

Comment: Or you can flip every other strip in order to have the shortest data paths. Just keep in mind the direction of each strip if you do.

Comment: Right, so something like this? https://i.imgur.com/MusZ8Hc.png

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the confirmation :-)